# RhinoMocks Expect not working as 'expected'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have the following test code

```
//setup the mock
SomeResource mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SomeResource>();
mock.Stub(m => m.GetNumOfResources()).Return(1);
mock.Stub(m => m.SomeProp).Return(SomeEnum.YO);
mock.Expect(m => m.SomeProp).Repeat.Once();
mock.Replay();

//execute
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.SetSomeResource(mock);
sc.MethodToTest();

//verify
mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

I want to verify that SomeProp was accessed.  Whenever I debug through the code I can see that `SomeProp` is being accessed, and yet the expectation I set up above is throwing an exception in the test, saying it wasn't.  I'm new to Rhino Mocks so I've clearly not set something up correctly but I cannot see what.  Any ideas?

Edit: Here's basically the code/logic I am testing:

```
private bool MethodToTest()
{
    bool ret= false;

    if (resource == null)
    {
        try
        {
            resource = new SomeResource();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log some error
        }
    }

    if (resource != null && resource.GetNumResources() > 0)
    {
        bool ok = true;

        try
        {
            resource.SetSomething("blah");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ok = false;

            // Test that SomeProp was accessed here
            SomeEnum val = resource.SomeProp;
        }

        ret = ok;
    }


    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Show the code under test including all relevant members being accessed by the test

Comment: While I can assume what `SetSomeResource` does you should include that as well.

Comment: Also based on the current code you need to make the mock throw an error when `SetSomething` is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of API confusion between mocks and stubs as they relate to Rhino Mocks API and interaction based testing

```
//Arrange
SomeObj mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SomeObj>();
mock.Expect(_ => _.GetNumOfThings()).Return(1);
mock.Expect(_ => _.SetSomething(Arg<string>.Any())).Throw(new Exception());
mock.Expect(_ => _.SomeProp).Return(SomeEnum.YO).Repeat.Once();
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.SetSomeResource(mock);

//Act
sc.MethodToTest();

//Assert
mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Reference [Rhino Mocks - Stub .Expect vs .AssertWasCalled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075393/5233410)