# Rhino Mocks async unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, rhino-mocks

**Environment**
Rhino Mocks version: 3.6.1
Visual Studio: 2017
Resharper: 2017.3.3
Nunit: 2.6.4

I run the 2 test fixtures together using Resharper. When I do so I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Previous method 'IService.DoThing();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
>      at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.AssertPreviousMethodIsClose()
>      at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.Replay()
>      at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.ReplayCore(Object obj, Boolean checkInsideOrdering)
>      at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
>      at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
>      at MobileServices.Api.Tests.Unit.TestFixture2.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\SCM\MyProject.Tests.Unit\ExampleTests.cs:line 42
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncInvocationRegion.AsyncTaskInvocationRegion.WaitForPendingOperationsToComplete(Object invocationResult)
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunAsyncTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)

When I run the two test fixtures multiple times, the test source for the error changes constantly between TestFixture1.Test1 to TestFixture2.Test1. When I run the test fixtures in isolation everything passes. Is this an issue with Rhino Mocks and threading?

```
using Project.Tests.Unit.SupportingClasses;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Rhino.Mocks;

namespace Project.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestFixture1
    {
        private IService _service;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _service = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IService>();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            _service.Stub(s => s.DoThing()).Return(Task.FromResult(true));

            var response = await _service.DoThing();
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestFixture2
    {
        private IService _service;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _service = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IService>();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            _service.Stub(s => s.DoThing()).Return(Task.FromResult(true));

            var response = await _service.DoThing();
        }
    }
}

namespace Project.Tests.Unit.SupportingClasses
{
    public interface IService
    {
        Task<bool> DoThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: does the same happen if you use `Expect` vs `Stub`? Reference [Rhino Mocks - Stub .Expect vs .AssertWasCalled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075393/5233410)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your code proves that `Rhino Mocks` **is not thread safe**. I'd advise you to use [`Moq`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) since it should work well in parallel.